# SFDX force:data:tree:export Invalid SOQL Query When Using File Path to Supply Query

Tags: data-export, salesforcedx, scratch-org

When using the sfdx force:data:tree:export command, the Salesforce Developer Documentation states you can specify a file path in place of an in-line typed query (either option would follow the -q flag). I ran a simple query using the in-line version first :

```
sfdx:force:data:tree:export -q "SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 5" -d queries/accounts/ -u DevHub
```

And it created the json and path files without issue.

However, when I tried to swap out the in-line query for a file path directed at accountsquery.file which contains the exact same query string, I keep getting the following error:

```
➜  testProject sfdx force:data:tree:export -q queries/accountsquery -d queries/accounts/ -u DevHub

ERROR:  Invalid SOQL query: "select id from account".
```

Does the file need to be of a certain extension type? Is the syntax somehow different when you specify a file path? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I can't find an example of using the file path over an in-line string anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried executing by create a simple file in a folder as shown in the below screenshot and below command worked fine

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q data/accounts/queryFile -d data/accounts/
```

My folder structure is as below and you can see i have a file shown in the editor

[image]

And you can see I have a file queryFile which does not have any extension .

The command line results are fine .

**Looks like the file does not need to enclose query in double quotes and thats your issue .**

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same issue and figured it out. Thought I would post here in case it helps someone in the future. In my case, the `.soql` file should not have anything other than the query text. All I needed to do was remove the comments in the file and everything worked fine. So, for example, with the default `account.soql` file that comes with a new sfdx project you just need to make the following changes.

**Change this**

```
// Use .soql files to store SOQL queries.
// You can execute queries in VS Code by selecting the
//     query text and running the command:
//     SFDX: Execute SOQL Query with Currently Selected Text

SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
```

**To this**

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
```